# How to create new user with sudo access

Tags: sudo, 15.04, users, administrator

My attempts at trying to create a new user on Ubuntu 15.04 desktop have been unsuccessful.

Sure, I get the new user and the login works and all seems fine. But then I can't use anything requiring `sudo`. The new user doesn't seem to be in the "sudo group".

How can I create a truly new user with full administration rights (install, update, etc.) ?

Answer (score 0):

to give a new-user a root privilege open terminal by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

then copy past this to it: `visudo`

search for this line:

```
# User privilege specification
 root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

then add this line to it:

```
newuser ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

replace the newuser with your new user-name.

it should be like this after adding that:

```
# User privilege specification
 root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
 newuser ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

then exit the file by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

Press <kbd>Y</kbd> when asked then <kbd>enter</kbd>